# Finding Duplicate Records on Different Criteria

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a group of queries that find instances of duplicate records with matches across several columns, some of them being exact matches and some being similar matches. I believe all of these queries *should* be very similar with just a few changes to the filters for the different variations, but I may be mistaken.

Two examples:

- A query to find all instances of records with identical matches in columns A, B, D, and E with C and F being shown in the results but not needing to have any duplication.
- A query to find all instances of records with identical matches in Columns A, B, and D, while E just has to be similar to other like records. (again C and F being shown in the results but not needing to have any duplication)

SQL is a language I have some familiarity with but am on a whole, a novice. So far I have tried to use GROUP BY and a HAVING statement to find instances where the count of the group is > 1, but I can only get this to work with the identical matches and can only see the columns used in the GROUP BY (no C and F). I have figured out that I can use levenshtein distance to find the similar instances cleanly, but I have not been able to work out how to integrate this into the GROUP BY formula.
Any advice on this would be helpful, feel free to ask any questions.
Thanks

This block is as far as I have got in an example with 3 identical columns and one similar, it produces some accurate results but also a handful of records that will only have a single of the necessary matches, I am unsure why. I am not married to having the query work this way, this is just what I came up with.  E & R Keys are unique identifiers necessary for later processing.

```
WITH A AS (

SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "Tickets"."id", "Tickets"."vid" ASC) AS RowNo,
to_hex(MD5( TO_UTF8( CONCAT( "Tickets"."vid" ,"Tickets"."id" , "Tickets"."num", cast("Tickets"."date"as varchar) )))) AS R_KEY,
 "Tickets"."vid" AS "vid",
 "Tickets"."id" AS "id",
 "Tickets"."num" AS "num",
 "Tickets"."date" AS "date",
 "Tickets"."amount" AS "amount",
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "TicketsB"."vid", "TicketsB"."id" ASC) AS RowNo2,
to_hex(MD5( TO_UTF8( CONCAT( "TicketsB"."vid" ,"TicketsB"."id" , "TicketsB"."num", cast("TicketsB"."date"as varchar) )))) AS R_KEY2,
 "TicketsB"."vid" AS "vid2",
 "TicketsB"."id" AS "id2",
 "TicketsB"."num" AS "num2",
 "TicketsB"."date" AS "date2",
 "TicketsB"."amount" AS "amount2"

FROM
 TicketTable AS "Tickets",
 TicketTable AS "TicketsB"
WHERE "Tickets".vid = "TicketsB".vid
AND "Tickets".date = "TicketsB".date
AND "Tickets".amount = "TicketsB".amount
AND "Tickets".num != "TicketsB".num
AND levenshtein_distance("Tickets".num,"TicketsB".num) < 2
AND length("TicketsB".num) - length("Tickets".num) = 1

LIMIT 100000
)


SELECT to_hex(MD5( TO_UTF8( CONCAT(VID , cast(DATE as varchar), cast(AMOUNT as varchar) )))) AS E_KEY,
R_KEY, VID, ID, NUM, DATE, AMOUNT FROM A 
UNION
SELECT to_hex(MD5( TO_UTF8( CONCAT(VID , cast(DATE as varchar), cast(AMOUNT as varchar) )))) AS E_KEY,
R_KEY2, ID2, ID2, NUM2, DATE2, AMOUNT2 FROM A 

ORDER BY VID, DATE, AMOUNT
```

Comment: GROUP BY will not work with similarities.  I suggest using COUNT() OVER() window function to count the duplicates for each row, then use that value plus your similarity score as filters in an outer query

Comment: please post the query you tried with the similarity logic

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Hey wasntMe, thanks for the question. A suggestion for you: try to give more details on the title of the questions, so the users know what is it about. In your case, you can mention "Finding duplicate records using a different criteria in SQL". Also, it helps to mention or tag the SQL dialect you are using. Different databases support different SQL features.